# How to change state residence for tax purposes as a "digital nomad"

Tags: united-states, income-tax, primary-residence

I am currently paying taxes as a Kansas resident because this is where I last had a steady "home."  But the last 2 years I've been a so-called "digital nomad", and have spent less than 10% of the year in the US, and only about half of that time in Kansas (the rest of the time was visiting family, or attending work meetings in other states).

Kansas income tax rates are relatively low, but there are some states with even lower income taxes (i.e. 0% in AL, FL, NV, SD, TX, WA and WY).

The only address I have "maintained" in Kansas has been my sister's mailing address, so any mail I receive goes to her.  I neither own nor rent a dwelling in Kansas.

I'm wondering what would be required to change my tax residence to another state. What is the minimum time I must live in another state to change my residence status, for instance?

I realize it's fairly easy to pass the formal requirements for proof of residency, which often involve simply providing a bank statement or utility bill mailed to an address within the state in question.  See for instance this [wikihow article on obtaining Texas residency](http://www.wikihow.com/Become-a-Legal-Resident-of-Texas).

So my question is more about the implications beyond this.  If I rent a mailbox in Texas, update my bank statements to be sent there, then get a Texas state issued ID, and immediately leave the state to travel Europe and Asia again, will I be violating any laws, or be suspected of fraud or other impropriety?

Comment: Do you own/rent a residence in Kansas?

Comment: @Charles: Good question. No, I do not.  I've been using my sister's mailing address to receive any mail.

Comment: How does your work income come in? Are you self-employed, or are you receiving W-2 income?

Comment: Look for information about people living in RVs. There are "clubs" that will enable you to get a physical address and mail forwarding services. Here's an [article](http://www.technomadia.com/2012/07/chapter-9-nomadic-logistics-domicile-mail-taxes-banking-and-voting/) about it. A friend just did this, switching residency from CA to TX.

Comment: @mkennedy: I'm aware of such services (I actually use one, too).  I'm just concerned about whether that's "enough" to change my residence for legal/tax purposes. I'll read your artcile. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to read about Kansas residency rules, as establishing residency in a different State doesn't mean you automatically lose the residency in Kansas. On the other hand, you may be able to lose a State residency without acquiring any other, depending on the State laws (if you're moving out of the US).

According to [Kansas Revenue](http://www.ksrevenue.org/pdf/geninst08.pdf),

> A Kansas resident for income tax purposes is anyone who lives in
>   Kansas, regardless of where they are  employed. An individual who is
>   away from Kansas for a period of time and has intentions of returning
>   to Kansas  is a resident.

As you can see, residency in any other State is not directly linked to residency in Kansas, but can help establishing intentions of (not) returning. However, establishing residency in a different country will help just as well.

Comment: Down voter, care to comment?